# Facing issue while using composition with a parent and a base component for react.js/typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

What i'm trying to achieve is to have a BaseComponent which will be reuse in different ParentComponent.

My base card component props is ->

```
export type MSGameCardProps = {
  title: string;
  fetchGamesFn : (searchText: string) => Promise<IResultObject<any,any>>;
};
```

My base card render all the necessary basic logics and controls (inputs,autocomplete,title).
For example, it provide an autocomplete which have a simple search debounce functionality.

Me parent component will not necessary have props and will use the base card like so :

```
export type MSGameSrcCardProps = {};

export const MSGameSrcCard: React.FC<MSGameSrcCardProps> = () => {

  const gameSvc = useGameService();

  const fetchGame = async (searchText: string) => {
    const rs = await result(gameSvc.getAll(searchText));
    return rs;
  };

  return (
    <MSGameCard title={"Convert From"} fetchGamesFn={fetchGame}></MSGameCard>
  );
};
export default MSGameSrcCard;
```

The parent component will provide a fetchGames function which can be different.
It will also set the title and may later on set some other flags.

This pattern result with this error : `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'MSGameCardProps': title, fetchGamesFn` when trying to use the parent component in my page like so : `<MSGameSrcCard></MSGameSrcCard>`

I don't understand why my parent should have those properties since they are only required in the child component and are fullfill in my parent component function.

I don't want to make them optional(?) since they are actually required; of course only for my base component

I did try to export my basecomponent ***AS ANY*** which remove the error but now my props.fetchGamesFn is always undefined even passing it in inside my parent component function.

Maybe i'm doing it wrong but is there a way to have a parent components with no props with child that required props?

**EDIT :** Here is my MSGameCard base component definition

```
export const MSGameCard: React.FC<MSGameCardProps> = props => {


  const [games, setGames] = React.useState([
    {
      name: ""
    }
  ]);
  const [selectedGame, setSelectedGame] = React.useState<any>();
  const [previousGame, setPreviousGame] = React.useState<any>();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);

  const [opacity, setOpacity] = React.useState(0);

  const fetchGameBase = (searchText: string) => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    console.log(props.fetchGamesFn);

    props.fetchGamesFn(searchText).then(rs =>{
      if (rs.isSuccess) setGames(rs.result.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    })

  };

  const searchDebounce = debounce(300, fetchGameBase);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchGameBase("");
  }, []);

  const onGameChanged = (event: any, value: any) => {
    if (selectedGame) setPreviousGame(selectedGame);

    setOpacity(0);

    if (value) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setSelectedGame(value);
        setOpacity(0.2);
      }, 300);
    }
  };

  const onInputChanged = (e: any) => {

    let value = e.target.value;
    if (!value) value = "";

    searchDebounce(value);

  };

  const getSelectedGameImg = () => {
    const bgUrl: string = selectedGame
      ? selectedGame.bg_url
      : previousGame?.bg_url;
    return bgUrl;
  };

  return (
    <Card style={{ position: "relative", zIndex: 1 }} variant="outlined">
      <CardContent style={{ zIndex: 1 }}>
        <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
          {props.title}
        </Typography>

        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <Autocomplete
              options={games}
              getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
              onChange={onGameChanged}
              onInputChange={onInputChanged}
              renderInput={params => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  label="Source game"
                  fullWidth
                  InputProps={{
                    ...params.InputProps,
                    endAdornment: (
                      <React.Fragment>
                        {isLoading ? (
                          <CircularProgress color="primary" size={30} />
                        ) : null}
                        {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                      </React.Fragment>
                    )
                  }}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container direction="row" spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <TextField label="DPI" fullWidth />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <TextField label="Sensitivity" fullWidth />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </CardContent>
      <img
        style={{ opacity: opacity }}
        className="gameImage"
        src={getSelectedGameImg()}
      />
    </Card>
  );
};

export default MSGameCard;
```

Comment: Can you please include how you defined `MSGameCard`? Is it typed correctly?

Comment: @stackoverflow-newbie just did!

Comment: @Pilouk Just checked code with no error found, shall I detail it as an answer?

Comment: @keikai i mean if u are able to resolve the 'type' error, yes ?

Answer (score 1):

Keep updating notice

---

After checked the `minimum reproducible example` you have provided.

I found no type error, am I missing something?

> Since the error occurred in both two props, I would leave only the string for the check

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export type MSGameCardProps = {
  title: string;
};
export type MSGameSrcCardProps = {};

export const MSGameSrcCard: React.SFC<MSGameSrcCardProps> = () => {
  return <MSGameCard title={"Convert From"} />;
};

const MSGameCard: React.SFC<MSGameCardProps> = (props: MSGameCardProps) => {
  console.log(props); // Object {title: "Convert From"}
  return <></>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MSGameSrcCard />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Try it online here:

[image: Edit vigorous-resonance-zw2ko]